# Rails 4: is it possible send Ajax .get request to same current page controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have my js.erb file firing off an ajax request while I'm on the root page (application.html.erb). Can my ajax .get pull a variable containing current_user from Application#index?

```
ApplicationsController
...
def index
@trackers =current_user.trackers.where(viewed: false).count
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to respond with JSON. I suggest you read this guide:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just access the helper method directly in the js.erb file?

```
<%= current_user %>
```

Otherwise, you could just store it in an instance variable like @trackers?

```
def index
  @trackers =current_user.trackers.where(viewed: false).count
  @user = current_user if current_user && signed_in?
end
```

The signed_in? method assumes you're using devise for authentication.